# Get Set<String> from ArrayList<MyObject>

Tags: java

I have a `School` class which has a name `String` field.

```
public class School {
   private final String name;

   public School(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   // getter and setter ...

}
```

I got an `ArrayList` of `School` instances:

```
List<School> shoolList = // Got value of ArrayList<School>
```

I would like to get a `Set<String>` which contains all school names from above `List`. I tried using `map()` of stream API:

```
schooList.stream().map(school -> school.getName())
```

But is there a easy way to get a `Set<String>` type result from above result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Collectors`:

```
Set<String> allNames = schoolList.stream()
    .map(School::getName)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

For more info, see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html